# Remove PayPal Express Checkout from StoreView

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal

I have two store views which share the same product category and on one of them I want to disable PayPal Express Checkout.

This cant be done in the back-end without disabling it for both store views.

What I have tried so far is:

config.xml in app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <class>Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model</class>
            </zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>zerosubtotalpaymentmethod/observer</class>
                        <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
                    </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Observer.php in app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/Model

```
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {


        /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();


        if($method->getCode()=='paypal_express_checkout')
        {   $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()=='wa'){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I am not sure exactly what the `$method->getCode()` is. does this code look right for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way but it is a dirty way but I will show you anyway.

I went into the `payment_methods.phtml` file in my one step checkout module and wrapped the payment methods in an `IF` statement like such:

original:

```
<?php if( sizeof($this->getMethods()) > 1 ): ?> 
    <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="save_shipping_method(shipping_method_url,0,update_payment_review);" <?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio validate-one-required-by-name" />
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio validate-one-required-by-name " onclick="save_shipping_method(shipping_method_url,0,update_payment_review);" /></span>
<?php endif; ?>
    <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->getMethodTitle($_method) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
```

After:

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()=='Store_View_Code'):?>
        <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio validate-one-required-by-name " onclick="save_shipping_method(shipping_method_url,0,update_payment_review);" /></span>
        <?php else: ?>

<?php if( sizeof($this->getMethods()) > 1 ): ?> 
    <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="save_shipping_method(shipping_method_url,0,update_payment_review);" <?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio validate-one-required-by-name" />
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio validate-one-required-by-name " onclick="save_shipping_method(shipping_method_url,0,update_payment_review);" /></span>
<?php endif; ?>
    <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->getMethodTitle($_method) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>

<?php endif; ?>
```

All I have done is strip what I don't need out and then I have added a custom Header for the Payment method I am using.

This may not work if you have more than 2 payment methods :)